# Can microservices be implemented without web services?

Tags: java, scala, akka, microservices

We are currently planning to migrate our production application to Microservices. Our application is currently implemented using Scala and Akka, because it uses high concurrency to process items that are delivered via MQ, this is a Messaging application (delivers mails and sms). We have a few services exposed with REST, but the main processing is done via MQ and some other tasks by doing batch processing, the question here is if the MQ part can be migrated to a RESTful approach, and how to achieve that grade of high concurrency, if it cannot be created as REST resource can it be kept as a Microservice which will be continuously listening to a MQ (JMSListener), as it is now? Thanks.

Comment: "Microservice" is just a description of a common pattern for designing server applications. Message-driven services are an ordinary component of such applications (though note that it's frequent for them to still have HTTP server functionality for monitoring).

Comment: IMHO I like to use message-passing whenever possible, partly for the reasons you allude to: more flexibility, loose-coupling, easier to handle the situation where the message processor goes down. I would therefore not convert from MQ to REST unless the situation really called for it.